# Change link for "add new" buttons on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

I know how to use capabilities to remove the "Add New" functionality for a custom post type, but what I really need to do is change the target of those links. Does anyone know how I might go about doing that?

I would be an "external" link (to the front end of the website) and not a page on wp-admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in most of the case WordPress ui uses `admin_url()` function to retrieve administrative urls. so you can use `admin_url` filter to modify that.

Example:

```php
add_filter( 'admin_url', 'wpse_271288_change_add_new_link_for_post_type', 10, 2 );
function wpse_271288_change_add_new_link_for_post_type( $url, $path ){
    if( $path === 'post-new.php?post_type=your_custom_post_type' ) {
        $url = get_permalink(/*your post ID here*/); // or any other url
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Change `your_custom_post_type` with your custom post type name.

Reference (WordPress Version 4.8): [edit.php (Line No. 312)](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-admin/edit.php#L312) and [link-template.php (Line No. 3132)](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L3132)

Comment: glad it worked! don't forget to check user's role/permission before allow them to create/edit content from your custom form... :)